# How to upload Photo when Input type is not 'File' in Selenium Webdriver by Using Java

Tags: java, css

```
<span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus avatarUploacIcon"></span>
Upload profile image</span>
```

i am using below code..

```
 WebElement uploading=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class='form_advanced_wrapper my-events_host_wrapper'] span[class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus avatarUploacIcon']"));
         uploading.click();
         uploading.sendKeys("C:\pic.jpg");
```

I have reached proper direction  but not upload any image, please help my
I have applied more and more syntax but not success to upload image because my type is not 'File'.
If any one use image upload without File type , 
Please share me how to use this ...............

Comment: Why not use input type="file" what's wrong with it?

Comment: i do not no about dear my developers not use any file type because i am uploading any photo then my photo is show without button click,

Comment: if its about styling then add a hidden input type="file" and trigger it on span click

Comment: How to use Gourav Plz type script for uploading file..

Answer (score 0):

```
    Finally, I  got it answer  when Input Type is not "File"....
Thanks Everyone Who suggest me......



public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
            {
                WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                String appUrl = "http://demo.theupbeetkitchen.com/";
                driver.get(appUrl);
                driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                driver.findElement(By.id("customLogin")).click();
                 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                 String newSet = driver.getWindowHandle();
                 driver.switchTo().window(newSet);   
                 driver.findElement(By.id("login_div")).click(); 
                 driver.findElement(By.id("ID")).sendKeys("mr.saurabh.gupta92@gmail.com");
                 driver.findElement(By.id("Password")).sendKeys("123456");
                 driver.findElement(By.id("loginButton")).submit();
                 driver.findElement(By.id("customWelcome Chef Saurabh Gupta!")).click();
                 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                 driver.findElement(By.className("btn")).click();
                 driver.findElement(By.id("photoVideoPage")).click();
                 Thread.sleep(2000);
                 WebElement uploading=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class='form_advanced_wrapper my-events_host_wrapper'] span[class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus avatarUploacIcon']"));
                 uploading.click();
                 uploadFile("C:\\pic.jpg");
                 System.out.println("Successfully Done...........");
            }
            public static void uploadFile(String fileLocation) 
            {
                try
                {
                    setClipboardData(fileLocation);
                    Robot robot = new Robot();  
                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
                    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
                    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
                    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
                    robot.delay(2000);
                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

                } 
                catch (Exception exp) 
                    {
                        exp.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
            private static void setClipboardData(String string) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(string);
                   Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(stringSelection, null);

            }
```